# Are these numbers unique?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

Grandpa loves numbers. He is always asking me riddles about them. (Annoying if you ask me)

He says:

> "These numbers are different than others. Even unique you might say.
>   There may be others in this group but I think I captured most
>
> 8
>
> 2
>
> 45
>
> 4
>
> 1

Can you tell me why?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell Grandpa that I think he's talking about numbers that have

> single word homophones: 8 - ate, 2 - to/o, 45 ~ fortify, 4 - for/e, 1 - won.

Are these numbers unique - maybe could include

> 6  - sicks (Br informal).

Comment: Grandpa does not know about 6 but other than that he agrees with you fully.

Comment: @DEEM - I will set forth on a $\pi$ which I spy with my $i$. Give my regards to Grandpa for this original series.

Comment: Great. Grandpa said that including "pi" would have given it away quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that

> all these numbers contains every letters that compose every number in 1-99, and none of the numbers from your list is composed with the letters from the others listed
>  I checked by seeing if one of these number could be composed by all the other and I found that: 
> 8 : *g* and *h* don't appear in another number from the list
> 2: *w* doesn't appear in another number from the list
>  45: *y* and *v* don't appear in another number from the list
>  4: *u* doesn't appear in another number from the list
>  1: *n* doesn't appear in another number from the list

Comment: I don't understand how they are different/unique though.  for instance:  rot13(lbh pbhyq ercynpr rvtug jvgu rvtugl-svir naq gura lbh jbhyqa'g rira arrq sbegl-svir)

Comment: Good point SteveV

Answer (score 0):

I guess

> One number can be obtained using the other 4 numbers and basic mathematical operations such as +, -, ×, ÷ and square root.

For example,

> 8 = (square root( 45 + 4) + 2) - 1 and so on.

Comment: Note there is no MATH tag here